# missing points with m_map projections

Tags: matlab

I'm using the m_map package in matlab to produce a global map of some values.

Here is an example:

```
lat2 = [-54.54,-33.15,-8.64,-1.3,5.8,15.35,30.7,32.86,37.54,40.25,...
    43.84,45.95,47.65,49.38,51.04,53.33,54.70,56.33,58.59,60.02,60.84,...
    62.09,63.15,64.15,66.06];
lon2 = [-68.02,-52.84,26.39,33.22,37.54,-83.84,90.66,119.30,89.34,-121.19,...
    -77.76,-60.83,9.2,-94.91,-90.8,-100.13,-97.58,-76.29,-112.08,-106.06,...
    31.38,28.52,29.70,-108.45,30.97];

figure(1);
m_proj('Mollweide'); %clongitude, 0
m_coast('patch','k');
m_grid('xaxislocation','middle');
for i = 1:length(lat2);
    m_line(lon2(i),lat2(i),'marker','o','markersize',4,'color','k','MarkerFaceColor','r');
end    

figure(2);
m_proj('Mollweide','clongitude', 0);
m_coast('patch','k');
m_grid('xaxislocation','middle');
for i = 1:length(lat2);
    m_line(lon2(i),lat2(i),'marker','o','markersize',4,'color','k','MarkerFaceColor','r');
end
```

[image]

Using exactly the same lat and lon values in both projections. Why do the asian points not appear in the first map? They only seem to show if I don't set 0 to be the centre of the figure.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with m_map. The problem seems to be nothing east of 180W will plot. So in your first map:

```
m_plot(-175,-40,'r.') % this works
m_plot(175,-40,'r.') % this doesn't
```

but

```
m_plot(-185,-40,'r.') % same as second point above
```

works. Note that the opposite happens if you do

```
m_proj('Mollweide','clongitude', 240);
```

in this latter case, *only* data points on Asia are plotted.

A quick (but not great) workaround is to convert all your (+)longitude points to be (-)longitude.

p.s. you don't need that for loop:

```
m_plot(lon2,lat2,'ko','markersize',4,'MarkerFaceColor','r');
```